# UIPath - Convert list<Object> to strings

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to create a small RPA process, that scrapes a website for movie titles (and it's URL), and then output them to the user.

I am using UIPath for this.

I have a variable called `MovieSuggestions`, that is a `List<Object>` with the default value of `New List(Of Object)`

For each movie I have found (currently 3), I am adding it to the list by below code:

```vb
{
   "MovieName" = row.Item("MovieName").ToString, 
   "MovieURL" = row.Item("MovieURL").ToString
}
```

However, the above will produce the below result for `MovieSuggestions`:

```vb
List<object>(3) { bool[2] { false, false }, bool[2] { false, false }, bool[2] { false, false } }
```

I am new to VB.Net so please bear with me if this is basic stuff.

*Edit*:

Adding items to dictionary in a loop:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is actually a **comparison** and not an assertion:

```
{
   "MovieName" = row.Item("MovieName").ToString, 
   "MovieURL" = row.Item("MovieURL").ToString
}
```

But you wanted to do it as follows:

```
{
   row.Item("MovieName").ToString, 
   row.Item("MovieURL").ToString
}
```

This would add the both `Strings` to your `List`.

But then you miss the possibility to name your entries. So instead you maybe want to swap to a `Dictionary` that is able to save a `String` that is naming the item and an `Object` that is flexible to store any data that might come. Doing that as follows:

```
New Dictionary(of String, Object)
```

Then using the `assign` activity to fill it:

[image: assign activity]

Then you have have a container for any `key values` you have.

Comment: I see! So I need to use a dictionary. I come from a PHP background, so essentially I am trying to end up with an array, containing all the different movies and urls:
`[{
   "MovieName": "Avatar",
   "MovieURL" = "http://....",
},{
   "MovieName": "Batman",
   "MovieURL" = "http://....",
}]`

Please see my updated OP - can I do it like that?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can also abuse the List like adding both, and on the iteration you remember that first is this and second is that. But that makes it complicated. You go better with my solution I think.